# what is wrong with this code? It doesn't work

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, rtc

```
#include <DS1302.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Time t;
Servo myservo;
int Hour;
int Min;
int Sec;
// Init the DS1302
DS1302 rtc(2, 3, 4);

void setup()
{
myservo.attach(9); 
myservo.write(45); 
// Set the clock to run-mode, and disable the write protection
rtc.halt(false);
rtc.writeProtect(false);
Serial.begin(9200);
// The following lines can be commented out to use the values already stored in the DS1302
//rtc.setDOW(SUNDAY); // Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
//rtc.setTime(8, 59, 50); // Set the time to 12:00:00 (24hr format)
//rtc.setDate(8, 25, 2019); // Set the date to August 25th, 2019
}

void loop()
{
t = rtc.getTime();
Hour = t.hour;
Min = t.min;
Sec = t.sec;
 Serial.print(Hour);
 Serial.print(":");
 Serial.print(Min);
 Serial.print(":");
 Serial.println(Sec);

//set the time for fish feeding 
if ((Hour== 2 && Min== 0 && Sec== 2)||(Hour== 21 && Min== 0 && Sec== 2)) {
myservo.write(0);
delay (300);
myservo.write(45);
delay (300);}
}
```

Comment: did the intermediate code work?

Comment: Nope, nothing seems to work hahaha

Comment: You need to define "doesn't work". What output are you expecting? What output do you get? What happens? It's like going to a doctor and saying you feel sick. S/he needs more details than that.

Comment: on your previous post, i suggested that you print a message when the seconds is 10 ... did that work?

Comment: Serial.begin(9200) ? and depending on the library, the rtc.get time may get stuck in a bad connection to the rtc chip.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could answer Nick Gammon's question. "Doesn't work" is not a useful description of a problem. Also `Serial.begin(9200);` will very likely not give any useful output on the serial console.

Comment: Nick, I was expecting the servo to rotate when the defined time. It doesn't do that. The servo doesn't move at all. 
- I've changed the serial.begin(9200) to (9600) but it doesn't seem to make a difference in the output.

Comment: I would break this down to individual problems by 1st commenting out the servo code and making sure the time code works AS EXPECTED. Then doing the same for the servo code.  If the clock does not work AS EXPECTED double check things such as using the correct pins to interface the RTC board to the ARDUINO UNO or if the RTC battery is still good.  If the servos do not work AS EXPECTED double check things such as using the correct pin to control the servo, the servo ground and power wires are correctly connected and if the poser supply is powerful enough to operate the servo.

Comment: @st2000 I think that the only thing I didn't cover so far is if the correct pins are being used. How do I check that?

Comment: Quit re-posting (3 times so far) your question!  People are going to start closing them down.  Instead - edit your original question.

Comment: In the line "DS1302 rtc(2, 3, 4);" you are tellng the program you will be connecting the Dallas Semiconductor clock chip to pins 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112989/discussion-on-question-by-tiago-kotryk-code-for-fish-auto-feeder-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation about the multiple time execution**

```
if ((Hour== 9 && Min== 14)||(Hour== 21 && Min== 0)) {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
 }
```

1. Assume the time is 9:14:00 (9 hours, 14 minutes, 00 seconds).. the `if` condition passes.
2. The for loop will get executed. The duration needed to complete the loop is roughly 5 seconds.
3. Later, it will again go to the if condition. The time will be now 9:14:06.. it means, the condition will pass again.. the motor will again rotate.. this will repeat for about 11 times.. until the time changes to 9:15:00 or more.
4. So the solution is to give a delay, before exiting the `if` loop if you wait for a minute with

   delay(60000);

then, the next 'if' condition will fail and works as per your expectation.

---

**Part 2:**

debugging:

```
        if ((Hour== 9 && Min== 14)||(Hour== 21 && Min== 0)) {
          for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
            // in steps of 1 degree
            myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
            delay(15);
            Serial.println("moving");
    ....
```

[image]

Comment: Like this?
`void loop() {
t = rtc.getTime();
Hour = t.hour;
Min = t.min;
Sec = t.sec;
// Serial.print(Hour);
// Serial.print(":");
// Serial.print(Min);
// Serial.print(":");
 Serial.println(Sec);
  
//set the time for fish feeding 
if ((Hour== 11 && Min== 46 && Sec== 0)||(Hour== 21 && Min== 0 && Sec== 0)) {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);                       
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
    myservo.write(pos); 
    delay(15);
  }
  delay(60000);
 }
}`

Comment: But anyways, the issue here is that the servo doesn't even start either way!

Comment: you should check the Servo connections once. I doubt on that

Comment: It's all fine with the connections, I just tested the servo with the servo sweep exemple code

Comment: I just added the simulation snapshot. I created using the wokwi Arduino simulator.. it works just fine.. nevertheless, can you use some print statements to see whether the IF condition is passing ever?

Comment: I am a total noob in arduino and coding. I understant what you suggest by using some print statements to see if the IF condition is passing, but I have no idea on how to do it. I'm sorry for bothering you with so much. :\

Comment: @TiagoKotryk insert `Serial.println("moving");` into the brackets of the if statements. Though at that point you should step back a bit and first do some basic Arduino tutorials to learn the basics. I don't think, that you really understand the code, that you wrote there, but that you just copy&pasted it together. It will get easier, when you understand the basics

Comment: @chrisl You are right about the point you made. Thank for your suggestion. I've inserted the code into the brackets and it shows here "Moving" on every second of the clock! Does it mean that the servo is trying to move every sec?

Comment: Yes. Though it is nor clear, what code you are currently using. Add the new code version to your question (leaving the old part intact)

Comment: @chrisl have updated this thread with the current code and results so you can take a look. Thanks for the huge help!

Comment: you have put the print statement outside the `for` loop. Please put it inside the for loop. you can put it after the line `delay(15)`

Comment: @goodarduinocode I have made the change:
`
 for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    Serial.println("moving");
  }
 }
}
`
But as result, the monitor serial displays nothing

Comment: The condition to drive the motor is never `passing`. Please take time and try to understand. Is the RTC running? Can you debug the time? Print the time and see

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you have given the baud rate as 9200 but the minimum baud rate is 9600(Serial.begin(9600)). And change the baud rate in the serial monitor.

Comment: 4 hours before you posted your answer, Tiago Kotryk already replied in the comments that changing the baud rate to 9600 didn't make a difference. So why post this as an answer?